# Oozie not registering "mapred.input.dir.recursive" property

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I'm having an issue with Oozie. It doesn't register `mapred.input.dir.recursive` property from the Oozie workflow. That causes a problem for me because my mapred.input.dir contains files as well as sub directories that contain some more files. I've searched for the solution extensively, but I haven't been successful in finding one.

Any ideas, advice, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

mapred.input.dir.recursive is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive